# Accessing fields in a GO structure

Tags: go, aws-sdk, aws-sdk-go

I am new to the Golang world and trying to parse a `json` response returned by AWS API.

I've tried parsing the result by dot notation and seem to get success in the higher levels. Below is what my experimentation resulted to.

*For brevity I excluded other fields*

**Test 1**

```
fmt.Println(result)
```

returns

```
{
  DBClusterSnapshots: [{
      Status: "available"
    }]
}
```

**Test 2**

```
fmt.Println(result.DBClusterSnapshots[0])
```

returns

```
{
    Status: "available"
}
```

**Test 3**

```
fmt.Println(result.DBClusterSnapshots[0].Status)
```

returns what seem to be a reference to an object

```
0xc0001e74c8
```

Given the last example (Test 3) how do I parse it properly to get the value of `Status` which is `"available"`

Comment: `Status` seems to be a pointer, so dereference it if you want the string.

Comment: @mkopriva could you provide an example

Comment: `s := *p` (assign `s` the value pointed to by `p`)

Comment: @mkopriva Thanks!!

Comment: note: this has nothing to do with "parsing" nor "json". You have a Go value of a predefined struct type and you are trying to access it's fields using [*selector expressions*](https://golang.org/ref/spec#Selectors) (not dot notation)

Answer (score 0):

As pointed out by @mkopriva

`Status` is a pointer and therefore need to be dereference when intending to extract the string.

so to achieve extracting the value of status we can dereference it like this.

```
s := *result.DBClusterSnapshots[0].Status
fmt.Println(s)
```